# mount error 13 = Permission denied

Tags: linux, samba, fstab

One of my servers is set up to automatically mount a Windows directory using fstab.  However, after my last reboot it stopped working.  The line in fstab is:

```
//myserver/myfolder /mnt/backup cifs credentials=home/myfolder/.Smbcredentials
```

The `.Smbcredentials` file is:

```
username=myaccount
password=mypassword
domain=mydomain
```

I do a `mount -a` and I receive `mount error 13 = Permission denied`.  If I do this enough it will lock out my Windows account, so I know it's trying.  I've checked that my password is correct.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try mount from the command line with `mount -t cifs 
//myserver/myfolder /mnt/backup --verbose -o credentials=home/myfolder/.Smbcredentials` and add the debugging info (sanitized) to your question?

Comment: What's the distro and version of `cifs-utils` do you have installed? I've had this problem before and I believe it was due to an update.

Comment: this error most likely connects to `NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE` which you can see them in `dmesg`. I assume that the username and password were correct. Please make sure that the credential file using LINUX (LF -- \n) instead of WINDOWS (CRLF -- \r\n).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Thanks, but some more googling turned up the solution.  It was using the wrong security type by default; this command worked:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //172.16.1.5/myshare/ /mnt/myshare \
    -osec=ntlmv2,domain=MYDOMAIN,username=myusername,password=mypassword
```

Comment: This was it! Running `mount -t cifs //10.0.0.138/usb1_1 /mnt/usbdisk -ousername=theusername,password=thepassord,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,uid=root` on a Fedora 25 machine worked fine, but failed when I ran the exact same command on an openwrt box (Chaos Calmer 15.05.1). Adding `sec=ntlmv2` made it work there as well.

Comment: Came here trying to mount a Debian 9 AD member from a CentOS 6 non-member, and this got me close -- for my case the magic was `sec=ntlmssp`

Comment: The fix for me was to use the `domain` keyword and specify it apart from the username.

Comment: sec=ntlmv2 has the option I just needed for my smb access from Ubuntu 18.04 to Windows 10 share. Thanks, Pickle.

Comment: its quit simple you need to escape your password with> '  sudo mount -t cifs //172.16.1.5/myshare/ /mnt/myshare -o username=myusername,password='mypassword'

Answer (score 65):

A couple of things to check out. I do something similar and you can test mount it directly using the `mount` command to make sure you have things setup right.

#### Permissions on credentials file

Make sure that this file is permissioned right.

```
$ sudo ls -l /etc/smb_credentials.txt 
-rw-------. 1 root root 54 Mar 24 13:19 /etc/smb_credentials.txt
```

#### Verbose mount

You can coax more info out of `mount` using the `-v` switch which will often times show you where things are getting tripped up.

```
$ sudo mount -v -t cifs //server/share /mnt \
    -o credentials=/etc/smb_credentials.txt
```

Resulting in this output if it works:

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.1.14,unc=\\server\share,credentials=/etc/smb_credentials.txt,ver=1,user=someuser,domain=somedom,pass=********
```

#### Check the logs

After running the above mount command take a look inside your `dmesg` and `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog` files for any error messages that may have been generated when you attempted the `mount`.

#### Type of security

You can pass a lot of extra options via the `-o ..` switch to mount. These options are technology specific, so in your case they're applicable to `mount.cifs` specifically. Take a look at the `mount.cifs` man page for more on all the options you can pass.

I would suspect you're missing an option to `sec=...`. Specifically one of these  options:

```
   sec=
       Security mode. Allowed values are:
       ·   none - attempt to connection as a null user (no name)
       ·   krb5 - Use Kerberos version 5 authentication
       ·   krb5i - Use Kerberos authentication and forcibly enable packet 
           signing
       ·   ntlm - Use NTLM password hashing
       ·   ntlmi - Use NTLM password hashing and force packet signing
       ·   ntlmv2 - Use NTLMv2 password hashing
       ·   ntlmv2i - Use NTLMv2 password hashing and force packet signing
       ·   ntlmssp - Use NTLMv2 password hashing encapsulated in Raw NTLMSSP
           message
       ·   ntlmsspi - Use NTLMv2 password hashing encapsulated in Raw 
           NTLMSSP message, and force packet signing

       The default in mainline kernel versions prior to v3.8 was sec=ntlm. 
       In v3.8, the default was changed to sec=ntlmssp.
```

You may need to adjust the `sec=...` option so that it's either `sec=ntlm` or `sec=ntlmssp`.

#### References

- [Thread: mount -t cifs results gives mount error(13): Permission denied](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1871142)

Comment: Checking `dmesg` was very helpful. This answer was from 2014, and since then, the WannaCry exploitation of SMB1.0 has made it deprecated, so be sure to add `vers=2.0` or 2.1 or 3.0, whatever the server supports, as the default 1.0 will no longer be supported.

Comment: Just a heads-up: since the destination folder is under Windows, which often requires the change of password every once in a while, the password in the credential file may be invalid. `mount` command will not tell you such details.

Comment: I had to specify `sec=ntlm` to mount a Synology share, thanks a lot!

Comment: My colleague and me suck with this for 1.5 hours. I gave all my credentials to him, and he set something on server side, so don't forget to mention that there could be security problems on server side too.

Comment: `-v` option was the saviour for me, in the credentials file I had misspelt `username` as `usename` and so the resulting string was setting the user string as blank. Small typos really are a pain.

Comment: Thanks, great reply. Was struggling with the permissions on the credentials file and found other guidance not specific enough but this helped a treat.

Answer (score 15):

I ran into this problem and the issue turned out to be not formatting the values in my credentials file correctly.  I tried:

```
username=DOMAIN\mylogin
password=<password>
domain=FULLY.QUALIFIED.DOMAIN
```

I also tried:

```
username=myemailaddress@someplace.com
password=<password>
domain=FULLY.QUALIFIED.DOMAIN
```

And:

```
username=FULLY.QUALIFIED.DOMAIN\mylogin
password=<password>
domain=FULLY.QUALIFIED.DOMAIN
```

Once I just used my login username only:

```
username=mylogin
password=<password>
domain=FULLY.QUALIFIED.DOMAIN
```

I was able to get my cifs mount to succeed.

Comment: great explanation!

Comment: `FULLY.QUALIFIED.DOMAIN` did it for me, after struggling for an hour! Thanks! You can read your fully qualified domain with `$ hostname -f`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was my problem too. I had created the credentials file from Windows and the line endings (EOL) were Windows. When I changed them to Unix it worked.

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy spent 1 day debugging this until I saw your comment. Damn line endings!

Answer (score 3):

This add works on scientific Linux 6.6 (RedHat 6.6)

edit `/etc/fstab`
create file = `.credentials` (e.g. in `/etc` ) with this details :

```
username=value
password=value
domain=value

//SERVER/SHARE1 /mnt/SHARE1 cifs credentials=/etc/.credentials,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Comment: file_mode and dir_mode flags solved for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

For an AD environment, I have to leave and rejoin the domain.

```
net ads leave -U domain-admin-username

kinit domain-admin-username
net ads join -U domain-admin-username
systemctl restart smbd nmbd winbind
```

Not sure why this was necessary, but happened after a routine reboot for updates. There were no other indications of any AD related issues while receiving this error.

Comment: This is exactly what helped me