# Windows directories keeps getting unmounted on two identical Red Hat servers

Tags: ssh, mount, freeze

We have a pretty severe problem at my research center. I have, together with IT, set up an infrastructure like this:

Users use their laptops at their desks. They all have a home-folder at a storage server which they can mount on their laptops (works without problem). Then we have powerful servers, which the users can log into via SSH. On these servers all the home folders are also mounted so that the powerful servers can work on data on the storage servers via 1 Gbit/s network.

Everything worked like a charm but out of nowhere the mounting of the home folders on the analysis servers have started acting up. The mounting of the home folders on the user machines (including my own) works flawlessly every time. This indicates that nothing is wrong with the storage server (which is a Windows machine). The users have macs and I have an Ubuntu – both works fine. On the other hand – there are two analysis servers that work independently – both these are experiencing the same problem which indicates that something is wrong with the windows storage server OR it could still be the analysis servers since they are identical (coincidence that they started malfunctioning at the same time?)

On the servers (Red Hat) we use the same method to mount as we do on my Ubuntu machine: For each users there is a line in /etc/fstab that tells it to mount it on /fenix/users/all-the-user-folders and the permissions are as we like them.

The problem is that the folders stop to be mounted after a random amount of time (can be after 3 minutes- me still being logged in). Then when I try to ssh and “ls –l” inside one of the failed folders the whole terminal freezes and I cannot ctrl+c out of it. This freezing also happens when I try to tabulate my way to a folder that is not mounted. Sometimes a server reboot fixes it – temporarily. Sometimes it can be fixed by going in as root at doing “mount –a –v”. But then it always falls back to failing.
When doing “mount –v –a” is sometimes stops, and freezes (you can quit with ctr+c here), on a random line in fstab. It can be that it mount 5 successfully but it gets stuck on the last – or first. The username and pw used are for a super account and those credentials are correct (and stored unde /etc/.filename).

I have done:

```
strace ls /storage/users/failedfolder
```

to get some info but did not figure out what is was. Also done

```
strace mount –a –v
```

to see where it gets stuck. Did not help me.

I’m not that used to IT – I have learned what I have to – so please be gentle. The IT guy is gone for a couple of weeks and we need this to work asap. Not feasible to restart the servers all the time for a couple of minutes of successful mounting. So frustrating!

I will print the outputs below. The home folders live on a windows server at `//fenix/csan/users/user-folders` and we mount them on the servers at `/fenix/users/user-folders` usint NTFS (I guess). I guess the ending of the output are of interest. I don’t know if the attached info will tell anything about why it stops being mounted.

Seems to have problems here:

```
SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1,
```

fstab:

```
# Created by anaconda on Tue Sep  8 14:50:02 2015

# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
# /dev/mapper/rhel-root   /                       xfs     defaults        0 0 UUID=898ea02b-087a-4f09-a497-eb1b9abc0a92 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0 /dev/mapper/rhel-home   /home              xfs     defaults        0 0 /dev/mapper/rhel-swap   swap               swap    defaults        0 0

//fenix/csan/tools /fenix/tools cifs iocharset=utf8,credentials=/etc/.fenix,rw,uid=admin,gid=grp-csan@cmiv.local,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775 0 0 
//fenix/csan/users/robka /fenix/users/robka cifs iocharset=utf8,credentials=/etc/.fenix,rw,uid=robka@cmiv.local,gid=grp-csan@cmiv.local,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755 0 0 
//fenix/csan/users/saana /fenix/users/saana cifs iocharset=utf8,credentials=/etc/.fenix,rw,uid=saana@cmiv.local,gid=grp-csan@cmiv.local,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755 0 0 
//fenix/csan/users/davan /fenix/users/davan cifs iocharset=utf8,credentials=/etc/.fenix,rw,uid=davan@cmiv.local,gid=grp-csan@cmiv.local,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755 0 0
```

strace_ls_l_fenix_users_user_robka(malfunctioning user folder)

```
[root@maul ~]# strace ls /fenix/users/robka execve("/usr/bin/ls", ["ls", "/fenix/users/robka"], [/* 49 vars */]) = 0 brk(0)             
= 0x960000 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f287aa4e000 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=109600, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 109600, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f287aa33000 close(3)               
= 0 open("/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240d\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=147096, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 2246808, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f287a609000 mprotect(0x7f287a62a000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7f287a82a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x21000) = 0x7f287a82a000 mmap(0x7f287a82c000, 6296, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f287a82c000 close(3) 
= 0 open("/lib64/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \26\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=20024, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 2114112, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f287a404000 mprotect(0x7f287a408000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7f287a607000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f287a607000 close(3)                                = 0 open("/lib64/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\37\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=37056, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f287aa32000 mmap(NULL, 2130560, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f287a1fb000 mprotect(0x7f287a202000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7f287a402000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7000) = 0x7f287a402000 close(3)                                = 0 open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2107816, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 3932736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2879e3a000 mprotect(0x7f2879ff0000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7f287a1f0000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b6000) = 0x7f287a1f0000 mmap(0x7f287a1f6000, 16960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f287a1f6000 close(3) 
= 0 open("/lib64/libpcre.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=398272, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 2490888, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2879bd9000 mprotect(0x7f2879c39000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7f2879e38000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5f000) = 0x7f2879e38000 close(3)                                = 0 open("/lib64/liblzma.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000/\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=153192, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f287aa31000 mmap(NULL, 2245240, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f28799b4000 mprotect(0x7f28799d8000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7f2879bd7000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x23000) = 0x7f2879bd7000 close(3)                                = 0 open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19520, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 2109744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f28797b0000 mprotect(0x7f28797b3000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7f28799b2000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f28799b2000 close(3)                                = 0 open("/lib64/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\23\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19888, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 2113904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f28795ab000 mprotect(0x7f28795af000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7f28797ae000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f28797ae000 close(3)                                = 0 open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240l\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=142304, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f287aa30000 mmap(NULL, 2208864, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f287938f000 mprotect(0x7f28793a5000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7f28795a5000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f28795a5000 mmap(0x7f28795a7000, 13408, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f28795a7000 close(3)                                = 0 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f287aa2f000 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f287aa2d000 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f287aa2d800) = 0 mprotect(0x7f287a1f0000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7f28795a5000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7f28797ae000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7f28799b2000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7f2879bd7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7f2879e38000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7f287a402000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7f287a607000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7f287a82a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x61a000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0 mprotect(0x7f287aa4f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 munmap(0x7f287aa33000, 109600)          = 0 set_tid_address(0x7f287aa2dad0)         = 65187 set_robust_list(0x7f287aa2dae0, 24)     = 0 rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7f2879395780, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f287939e100}, NULL, 8)
= 0 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7f2879395810, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f287939e100}, NULL, 8) = 0 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0 getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0 statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", {f_type=0xf97cff8c, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0 statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", {f_type=0xf97cff8c, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0 stat("/sys/fs/selinux", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 brk(0)                    
= 0x960000 brk(0x981000)                           = 0x981000 open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106065056, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 106065056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f2872e68000 close(3)                                = 0 ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0 ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=24, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0 stat("/fenix/users/robka",
```

strace_mount_a_v

```
[root@maul ~]# strace mount -a -v execve("/usr/bin/mount", ["mount", "-a", "-v"], [/* 49 vars */]) = 0 brk(0)                              
= 0x7fd0f4e08000 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f2c91000 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=109600, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 109600, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0f2c76000 close(3)               
= 0 open("/lib64/libmount.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@\231\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=260784, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 2354496, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0f2832000 mprotect(0x7fd0f286f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7fd0f2a6e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3c000) = 0x7fd0f2a6e000 mmap(0x7fd0f2a70000, 3392, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f2a70000 close(3) 
= 0 open("/lib64/libblkid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \200\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=252696, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 2345800, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0f25f5000 mprotect(0x7fd0f262d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7fd0f282d000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x38000) = 0x7fd0f282d000 mmap(0x7fd0f2831000, 2888, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f2831000 close(3) 
= 0 open("/lib64/libuuid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=20032, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f2c75000 mmap(NULL, 2113920, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0f23f0000 mprotect(0x7fd0f23f4000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7fd0f25f3000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7fd0f25f3000 close(3)                                = 0 open("/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240d\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=147096, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 2246808, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0f21cb000 mprotect(0x7fd0f21ec000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7fd0f23ec000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x21000) = 0x7fd0f23ec000 mmap(0x7fd0f23ee000, 6296, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f23ee000 close(3) 
= 0 open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2107816, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 3932736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0f1e0a000 mprotect(0x7fd0f1fc0000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7fd0f21c0000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b6000) = 0x7fd0f21c0000 mmap(0x7fd0f21c6000, 16960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f21c6000 close(3) 
= 0 open("/lib64/libpcre.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=398272, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f2c74000 mmap(NULL, 2490888, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0f1ba9000 mprotect(0x7fd0f1c09000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7fd0f1e08000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5f000) = 0x7fd0f1e08000 close(3)                                = 0 open("/lib64/liblzma.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000/\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=153192, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 2245240, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0f1984000 mprotect(0x7fd0f19a8000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7fd0f1ba7000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x23000) = 0x7fd0f1ba7000 close(3)                                = 0 open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19520, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 2109744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0f1780000 mprotect(0x7fd0f1783000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7fd0f1982000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fd0f1982000 close(3)                                = 0 open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240l\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=142304, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f2c73000 mmap(NULL, 2208864, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0f1564000 mprotect(0x7fd0f157a000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0 mmap(0x7fd0f177a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7fd0f177a000 mmap(0x7fd0f177c000, 13408, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f177c000 close(3)                                = 0 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f2c72000 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f2c70000 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fd0f2c70880) = 0 mprotect(0x7fd0f21c0000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7fd0f177a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7fd0f1982000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7fd0f1ba7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7fd0f1e08000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7fd0f23ec000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7fd0f25f3000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7fd0f282d000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7fd0f2a6e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7fd0f2e9e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 mprotect(0x7fd0f2c92000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0 munmap(0x7fd0f2c76000, 109600)          = 0 set_tid_address(0x7fd0f2c70b50)         = 65262 set_robust_list(0x7fd0f2c70b60, 24)     = 0 rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7fd0f156a780, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fd0f1573100}, NULL, 8)
= 0 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7fd0f156a810, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fd0f1573100}, NULL, 8) = 0 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0 getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0 statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", {f_type=0xf97cff8c, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0 statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", {f_type=0xf97cff8c, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0 stat("/sys/fs/selinux", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 brk(0)                    
= 0x7fd0f4e08000 brk(0x7fd0f4e29000)                     = 0x7fd0f4e29000 open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106065056, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 106065056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0eb03d000 close(3)                          
= 0 getuid()                                = 0 geteuid()                               = 0 getuid()                                = 0 geteuid()                               = 0 getgid()                                = 0 getegid()                               = 0 prctl(PR_GET_DUMPABLE)                  = 1 lstat("/etc/mtab", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=17, ...}) = 0 getuid()                 
= 0 geteuid()                               = 0 getgid()                                = 0 getegid()                               = 0 prctl(PR_GET_DUMPABLE)                  = 1 stat("/run", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=1220, ...}) = 0 lstat("/run/mount/utab", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0 open("/run/mount/utab", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_CLOEXEC, 0644) = 3 close(3)  
= 0 getuid()                                = 0 geteuid()                               = 0 getgid()                                = 0 getegid()                               = 0 prctl(PR_GET_DUMPABLE)                  = 1 stat("/etc/fstab", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2547, ...}) = 0 open("/etc/fstab", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2547, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f2c90000 read(3, "\n#\n# /etc/fstab\n# Created by ana"..., 4096) = 2547 read(3, "", 4096)      
= 0 close(3)                                = 0 munmap(0x7fd0f2c90000, 4096)            = 0 open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2502, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f2c90000 read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2502 read(3, "", 4096)          
= 0 close(3)                                = 0 munmap(0x7fd0f2c90000, 4096)            = 0 open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) =
-1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY)
= -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY)
= -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/util-linux.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0f2c90000 write(1, "/                        : ignor"..., 35/     options: ip=10.208.21.247,unc=\\fenix\csan,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,uid=1000,gid=1777404792,user=maul,prefixpath=tools,pass=******** 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1, 0x7ffc16dd0d48, 0, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_value={int=11314776, ptr=0x7fab00aca658}} --- wait4(-1,
```

EDIT:
When mounting with mount -v -a it usually gets stuck, on a random folder, like this:

```
[root@maul ~]# mount -v -a
/                        : ignored
/boot                    : already mounted
/home                    : already mounted
swap                     : ignored
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.208.21.247,unc=\\fenix\csan,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,uid=1000,gid=1777404792,user=maul,prefixpath=tools,pass=********
```

Also, I tried to just mount my folder on the server, which works on my computer, but that did not work. So, the same command and same credentials works on my ubuntu but not on Redhat - even though it has worked before and still works for a short time after reboot. Black magic...

Comment: I don't know very much about cifs, but can you confirm that the user in /etc/.fenix has the right password and is not locked?

Comment: Yeah - because why would it work sometimes, and sometimes not. And work before. Also,both the servers use a different master accounts so the content in /etc/.fenix is different for them both. That these account would malfunction at the same time and only sometimes sounds improabable :(. I will ofcourse make the IT guy confirm this, but don't think this is it. Thanks tough!

Comment: in the hopes of clarifying/simplifying, you mention credentials in a "/etc/.filename" and also /etc/fstab's use of /etc/.fenix. Hopefully you're referring to the latter when you mention the former?

Comment: Also, maybe the Windows fileserver underwent an update that changed the required security option for mount.cifs? See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124342/mount-error-13-permission-denied for a bunch of ideas, including manually mounting with -v to see more messages.

Comment: Sorry if unclear: On each server the mounting commands are under /etc/fstab. These mounting commands use the credentials in .fenix, stored under /etc/.fenix. Will check out the link, thanks! But if the security was changed it should never work right? Now they are mounted for a while.