# RHEL - Mounting CIFS Permission Denied (Error code - 13)

Tags: rhel, samba, automounting, smb

I understand that a lot of people have posted on this issue, I have read through a whole lot of them before I try to post this question. I have tried the many of the provided solution, none have works for me so far, please help!

Background: I am trying to mount my samba share via the following command:

```
sudo mount -v -t cifs -o username=white,password=123,vers=2.0,sec=ntlmssp \
    //192.168.72.129/myshare /mnt/share
```

```
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.72.129/myshare
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
[root@localhost mnt]# sudo mount -v -t cifs \
    -o username=white,password=123,vers=2.0,sec=ntlmssp \
    //192.168.72.129/myshare /mnt/share
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.72.129,unc=\\192.168.72.129\myshare,vers=2.0,sec=ntlmssp,user=white,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

Above is the error message from the command and dmesg, I have tried several other sec options, same errors.

Below is my configuration for the share path within smb.conf:

```
[myshare2]
        comment = My share 2
        path = root/share2
        read only = No
```

I have also tried using a credentials file to mount, same error.

Please guide and advise on the matter, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mount error 13 = Permission denied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124342/mount-error-13-permission-denied)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have tried different sec options as suggested in that post, it does not works for me.