# Unable Mount Shared Windows Server Drive in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, windows, cifs

I am attempting to mount a shared drive located on a 2019 windows server(192.168.1.180) to my linux machine(Ubuntu 18.04). I've updated my fstab as you can see below and created a new directory for the mount (/mnt/remotebackupswintest). The shared drive only allows certain users but I am able to ping the device. I am also able to map the drive on my windows machine with the appropriate credentials; however, I am thinking that I probably did something wrong. I am not well versed in Linux so room for error is expected. Not sure if I am missing a domain or another *option* in my fstab or mount cmd but any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you all so much.

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation`
UUID=0b903abc-2db7-4b0d-a7e2-b04a2a6e9f34 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=369D-A7AB  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=8cdd9989-b101-4504-ae59-e6b9d1ccba7b       /mnt/sdb        ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=5674cc07-064a-44e9-82c6-01a501cd8fba       /mnt/sdc        ext4    defaults        0       2
//192.168.1.180/glservertest /mnt/remotebackupswintest cifs  vers=1.0,user=user_1
```

I run the following command:
`root@glserver:/# sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.180/glservertest /mnt/remotebackupswintest user=user_1, -o version=1.0`

I receive this error:
`mount error(22): Invalid argument Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

The log info says this:
`May 10 11:05:54 localhost kernel: [2847286.234589] CIFS: Unknown mount option "version=1.0"`
Note: Windows server has SMB 1.0/CIFS is installed.

EDIT: just tried `vers=` instead of `version=` and it produced the following error:

```
May 10 14:37:24 localhost kernel: [2859976.122955] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
May 10 14:37:24 localhost kernel: [2859976.122999] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

EDIT 2: I took away the `vers=` but now I am getting a `Device or resource busy`

Command used: `root@glserver:/# sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.180/glservertest /mnt/remotebackupswintest -o user=user_1`

Error: `May 10 15:55:27 localhost kernel: [2864659.611981] No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.`

`May 10 15:55:27 localhost kernel: [2864659.614555] CIFS VFS: ioctl error in smb2_get_dfs_refer rc=-5`

Comment: The error says that there is no option `version=`. See man page `man mount.cifs`. There is a `vers=`, try with that.

Comment: Ok thank you. I tried that but i get a permission denied... My credentials are correct. What else could it possibly be? Thanks!

Comment: You could check following this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124342/mount-error-13-permission-denied

Comment: Very helpful. Unfortunately, this is new for me and i don't have the first clue where our credentials are stored. We have a hybrid O365 environment.

Comment: Why are you trying to mount it with `cifs` version 1 anyway? Windows Server 2019 uses SMB 3.0 which the default of `cifs` in Ubuntu 18.04. Remove `vers=` and mount it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Took away the `vers=` but now I am getting a `Device or resource busy`.

Comment: Add the error to the question and the command or method that you used to mount it that led to the error.

Comment: That may also just be a warning. Have you verified that the share actually didn't mount? Instead of doing it manually, you can also just remove `vers=1` from `/etc/fstab` and just use the command `mount -a`. You don't need to prepend `sudo` to any commands as you are already in a root shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `version=` and making it `Read/Write` access to everyone resolved my issue.